# Is there way to convert air-application in flex-application

Tags: apache-flex, air, project

I need to convert complete .air project to flex project which can run in flash player in browser. Anybody do it?

Answer (score 1):

Look what's inside of .project file. I believe it is set here:

```
...
<natures>
    <nature>com.adobe.flexbuilder.apollo.apollonature</nature>
    <nature>com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.flexnature</nature>
    <nature>com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.actionscriptnature</nature>
</natures>
```

Apollo is codename for AIR. If you remove this nature, project *may* turn into Flex-based. Never did it myself though, so you have to experiment.

Comment: There seems to be a bit more to do, look at this post: http://soenkerohde.com/2008/05/change-project-from-flex-to-air/ Of course you should do it the other way round. As this post is from 2008 I don't know if something has changed since then.

Comment: I have created new Flex Project and copied content of "old" air project into it. Now I try to run flex project. It's very fun: I see white screen and nothing more.

Comment: @semen: If there is no error, you have converted your project. The white screen is imho another issue. But without more input a hint to solve this issue is nearly impossible :)

Comment: AIR and Flex are using different application classes and Flex has no access to AIR classes. Of course, code must be corrected.

Comment: Thanks, it's complex project with web-services calls, external configuration, lot of custom components, etc. I concluded to "build" project brick-by-brick=(

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the air-project. I don't think you can get an air-project running as a flex app if it uses air-only features like directory/file selectors or the like ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. I've built my project by simple copying the files one-by-one and correct the errors.